# Smart fastener for male thread in solidworks

Tags: solidworks

Is it possible to add nut using smart fastener feature in SolidWorks as shown below. Presently I have added nut using toolbox feature. I want to know if we can add nut and a washer to male thread directly using smart fastener feature rather than separately adding nut and washer from toolbox

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

This is known as a hardware stack, and the official SW help pages provides a clear explanation regarding setting these up: https://help.solidworks.com/2019/english/SolidWorks/sldworks/c_Smart_Fasteners_Hardware_Stacks.htm#voc1450446632618